# How to get reference to 'this' in jQuery outside the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that is triggered on programmatically clicking a `.special` link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.special').trigger('click');});
$(document).on('click', '.special', function(){
  var url  = $(this).attr('href');
  // More code that might depend on $(this)
});
```

The same code in the `on click` event above is also triggered when a user manually clicks on other links. So, somewhere in the footer I also have this code.

```
$('.manual').on('click', function() {
   var url  = $(this).attr('href');
  // More code that might or might not depend on $(this)
});
```

My problem is, I have to put the same code in two places (`.manual` as well as `.special` link). To avoid code duplication I replaced the manual code with the following and removed the special event above.

```
$(document).on('click', '.manual,.special', function(){
  var url  = $(this).attr('href');
  // More code that might depend on $(this)
});
```

However, the above code stopped working on `.special` link. My question is, if there is some way I can take the `$(this)` reference outside and call it like a function. Something along the lines of

```
function whenClicked() {
  var url  = $(this).attr('href');
  // More code that might depend on $(this)
}
```

and calling the `whenClicked` function like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.special', function(){
  whenClicked();
});

$('.manual').on('click', function() {
   whenClicked();
});
```

Although it would be more ideal if I could somehow combine both the `.manual` and `.special` as one like I tried above.

Comment: Are you asking about passing `this` as a parameter to a function?

Comment: Yes, I guess. All I want is that the code works on both these links without duplication.

Comment: You could use a callback which has `this` passed to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple ways how you can do it

**1** - pass function reference to `$.on`

```
$(document).on('click', '.special', whenClicked);
```

**2** - use `.call` or `.apply`

```
$(document).on('click', '.special', function(){
  whenClicked.call(this);
});
```

**3** - pass `this` as argument

```
$(document).on('click', '.special', function(){
  whenClicked($(this));
});

function whenClicked($element) {
  var url  = $element.attr('href');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply passing the desired element as a parameter?

```
function whenClicked($element) {
  var url  = $element.attr('href');
  // More code that might depend on $(this)
}
```

Note: I am assuming a jQuery element in this example

else for a DOM element

```
function whenClicked(element) {
  var url  = $(element).attr('href');
  // More code that might depend on $(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `this` prevents what you are trying; but you can solve it easily.

Your function should have a parameter ("t" is chosen below).

```
function whenClicked(t) {
  var url  = t.attr('href');
  // More code...
}
```

Then you should pass `$(this)` as the parameter when you call the function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.special', function(){
  whenClicked($(this));
});

$('.manual').on('click', function() {
   whenClicked($(this));
});
```